# I cant Autoexecute UPDATE in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to update my data, it doesn't. I have this code:

```
$rs2 = $DB->AutoExecute("Estructura",$reg1,'UPDATE', "Id_Padre 
                         LIKE '%".$varId_hijo."%'" );
```

My Id_Padre is a Varchar and the $varId_hijo is varchar

Comment: what frame work is this using?

Comment: @Dagon OP's ran off to school or bed. Please come back in about 12-18 hours for a response. *Thank you, come again.*

Comment: @Fred-ii- its Easter Sunday, perhaps hes in church

Comment: @Dagon *Ah,* I hadn't thought of that; good call. *Hop hop!*

Comment: what would your query in a plain sql query look like? do you get any errors?